# Bootstrap popup modal shifts when displayed

Tags: javascript, html, function, bootstrap-4, queryselector

I have a Bootstrap modal popup that displays when a "play" button is clicked. However, when it appears, the navigation seems to shift a little to the right. I can't understand why.

JS to trigger popup to appear once clicked on:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var url = $("BetterConnect").attr("src");
    $("#BetterConnect").on("hide.bs.modal", function () {
      $("#BetterConnect").attr("src", "");
    });
    $("#BetterConnect").on("show.bs.modal", function () {
      $("#BetterConnect").attr("src", url);
    });
  });
```

Once the popup is clicked, it looks like it is adding an inline style of **padding-right: 17px;** to the body tag. So I create a little snippet of JS so if the body tag has class of "modal-open", then add styling of padding: 0. However, it throws me this error and I can't understand why!

**Error**: `caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')`

HTML code screenshot where it adds padding-right:17px when class of `modal-open` appears:

[image]

Code to set padding to 0, so no shifting occurs:

```
  var bodyTag = document.querySelector("body");
  if (bodyTag.classList.contains(".modal-open")) {
    body.style.padding = "0";
  }
```

Any ideas why I am getting this error on such a simple snippet of code? Or does anyone have any better suggestions?

Comment: That error doesn't seem related. Please see [ask], then revise to put a demo snippet in your post using the editor. That's very easy to do with Bootstrap.